# call an external class from Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-class

I started to play around with calling an external class from jupyter notebook.  I am a bit baffled.  I added to the class 2 simple functions: for testing purpose the 2 functions return the same variables, and these variables get printed out in jupyter notebook. BUT it is working for one function only and not for the other !!? I saved multiple times the class file and jupyter file, I restarted the kernel multiple times.
here the class:

```
class DataSet:
  def __init__(self, slv_tuple, tec_name,projectID, sampleID):
    self.slv_tuple=slv_tuple
    self.tec_name=tec_name
    self.projectID=projectID
    self.sampleID=sampleID
 
 #function1 : it is working
 def dataSet_description(self):
    return "{} {} {} {}".format(self.slv_tuple, self.tec_name, self.projectID, self.sampleID)

 #function 2: it is not working
 def displayTest(self):
    return "{} {} {} {}".format(self.slv_tuple, self.tec_name, self.projectID, self.sampleID)
```

and here Jupyter Notebook

```
from ClassObject_1 import DataSet
ds_1=DataSet(slv_tuple, 'test', projectID, sampleID)

#No error
print(ds_1.dataSet_description())
#answer:('1,2,3',) test P12345678 S12345678

#ERROR
print(ds_1.displayTest())
#Attribute Error:DataSet Object has no attribute 'displayTest'
```

is there is any obvious reason why the displayTest() function is not working?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I was working with the wrong copy of the class (located in a different folder). Each time I updated the class, the update was not reflected in Jupyter Notebook...

Comment: Yes, once you import a class, you need to restart the kernel or reload the associated library. It's meant  to save resources as import is computationally expensive, but when you are learning it can be an issue. (So normally you could have `import pandas` multiple times in your code but it would only import it the 1st time.) See about the %autoreload magic [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/autoreload.html#autoreload) or use something like [this](https://www.pauldesalvo.com/how-to-refresh-an-imported-python-file-in-a-jupyter-notebook/), or restart the kernel.